# How to place the text on the right side of the image inside <figure>

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to simulate a car gallery by trying to put an image on the left side on the screen and adding the text directly right beside it. I have been trying to use the  and  tag to try and align both of them, but it hasn't worked out so far. Thanks for taking a look, sorry if this is a rookie mistake!

Already tried using sections, positions, floats,text-align,...

```css
figure {
  float: left;
}

figcaption {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 24px;
  height: 180px;
  text-align: center;
}

.imgpers {
  margin: 20px 20px;
  width: 20%;
  height: 20%;
}

.persOpties {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="persOpties">
  <figure>
    <img class="imgpers" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Opel Adam">
    <figcaption>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img class="imgpers" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Opel Astra">
    <figcaption>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figcaption>

  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img class="imgpers" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Opel Combol1">
    <figcaption>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figcaption>

  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img class="imgpers" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Opel Corsa">
    <figcaption>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figcaption>
  </figure>
</section>
```

Comment: You should use placeholders or random pictures that can we see.

Comment: oh sorry , i'm still kinda new to all of this

Comment: I've edited it for you. Plus you didn't close last <figure>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put `display: flex;` and `align-items: center;` on parent.

```css
figure {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

figcaption {
  padding: 15px;
}

.persOpties {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="persOpties">
  <figure>
    <img class="imgpers" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Opel Adam">
    <figcaption>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figcaption>
  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img class="imgpers" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Opel Astra">
    <figcaption>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figcaption>

  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img class="imgpers" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Opel Combol1">
    <figcaption>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figcaption>

  </figure>
  <figure>
    <img class="imgpers" src="https://via.placeholder.com/300" alt="Opel Corsa">
    <figcaption>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figcaption>
  </figure>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

```css
figure{
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}
figcaption {
}
.imgpers{
    margin: 20px 20px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 20%;
}
.persOpties {
    display:flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<section class="persOpties">
    <figure>
        <img class="imgpers" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Opel Adam">
        <figcaption>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img class="imgpers" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Opel Astra">
        <figcaption>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figcaption>

    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img class="imgpers" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Opel Combol1">
        <figcaption>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figcaption>

    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img class="imgpers" src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="Opel Corsa">
        <figcaption>naam: Opel Adam<br>prijs: 13.050,00</figcaption>

</section>
```

Comment: Thanks this looks great!  sorry if it was a rookie mistake

Comment: And why is that a correct answer? What is the difference?

Comment: No problem this is how we learn and help each other.
Can you please up vote if worked for you. Thank you.